# What is the impact if I compile Oracle 10g Objects without debug?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

In one of the Oracle 10g DB which I support - there are many DB objects which were created/compiled around 15 years back with debug enabled. Now I have been asked to compile them without debug enabled. I wanted to understand if this will have any impact both performance/functional to the existing functionality or not. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, nothing will happen (meaning: procedures will keep on working, they won't "break").

What you're about to do, is to `ALTER PACKAGE` (for packages) with the `DEBUG` option specified. It ...

> ... instructs the PL/SQL compiler to generate and store the code for use by the PL/SQL debugger

That leads to use of `DBMS_DEBUG` package.

Now: if those stored procedures were compiled with debug enabled, that might have been done with TOAD. If I remember well, years ago debug might even have been the default option, so all stored procedures got a nice *bug* icon displayed. However, if you aren't going to debug them (I thin you aren't), compiling in debug mode is unnecessary.

Stored procedures will keep working well, regardless debug mode being specified or not. If I were you, I'd recompile them without debug option. If necessary, you can easily recompile them again, this time with that option.

As @thatjeffsmith said in his comment: the impact will be *positive*, as everything should work better than with debug.

Comment: You shouldn't have DEBUG info collected on stored procs in PRODUCTION systems - it will add noticeable overhead and impact performance

Comment: I don't have it, @thatjeffsmith :) I should have said that - if compiled without debug - it might run *better* than before.

Comment: the question is, will it impact performance, the answer is yes - it should be better if no debug is attached

Comment: Thanks for the information @Littlefoot and thatjeffsmith 
Will get it done in next available slot, accepting your answer as of now.